.htaccess: Restrict access to specific file to one specific referrer
I have been struggling with this for hours, and cannot figure it out.
I have a PDF file. Let's say that it's stored on my website as https://example.com/data/fancy.pdf.
That PDF file should accessible only from a specific page on my website; let's call it https://example.com/format/showfancy/.
Any attempt to access that specific PDF file via a direct link, from another website, or even from the wrong page on my website, should be forbidden.
Note that the URL might have a query string after it, and that's acceptable, e.g. https://example.com/format/showfancy/?summary=true
This is what I think the commands should look like, but it doesn't work.
# Forbid an incorrect referrer.
<Files fancy\.pdf>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^/format/showfancy/
    RewriteRule - [forbidden]
</Files>

(I don't need to wrap this in a <Directory> directive, because the file name is unique on the website.)
I'm not even sure that this would reject another website using the same path, e.g. https://someone.com/format/showfancy/.
I've been experimenting with all sorts of combinations, and searching for ages, but found nothing that works. Everything that I try doesn't restrict the file, restricts it on the valid page, or returns a syntax error.
What commands should I be using, please?


<Files fancy\.pdf>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^/format/showfancy/
    RewriteRule - [forbidden]
</Files>


There are few issues here...

You should not include mod_rewrite directives inside a <Files> block - it's not officially supported and there is no need to anyway - since the URL/file check should be performed in the RewriteRule directive as the first argument (see next point).

You are missing the first argument to the RewriteRule directive. It will try to match the requested URL against -, which will fail.

The HTTP Referer is an absolute URL, starting with scheme and hostname. Here you are trying to test for a Referer that does not start with /format/showfancy/, which will always be successful (if the RewriteRule pattern matches - see above point).


Assuming the .htaccess file is in the root of the site then the rule should be like this instead:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com/format/showfancy/
RewriteRule ^data/fancy\.pdf$ - [forbidden]

This rule would need to be near the top of the .htaccess file, before existing mod_rewrite directives.
If you wish to remove the dependency on the data subdirectory (if any)  - if this filename is unique on your site - then you can change the RewriteRule pattern to (^|/)fancy\.pdf$.
Note that the URL-path matched by the RewriteRule pattern (first argument) does not start with a slash when used in a .htaccess (directory) context. And this matches against the URL-path only, not the query string. (In this example, any and no query string would be permitted on the requested URL.)
It is common to just use the short-hand flag F instead of forbidden.
Note that the HTTP Referer header can be easily faked if a user is so determined. (Although they would need to know what the expected value would be.)
And users can choose to suppress the Referer header entirely in the browser (in interests of "privacy"), so these users would not be able to access this resource.
UPDATE:
Using HTTP_HOST to avoid hardcoding the domain
As mentioned in comments, you can't use %{HTTP_HOST} directly in the 2nd argument of the RewriteCond directive (the CondPattern) since this is a standard regex (PCRE) and consequently does not support variable expansion. (%{HTTP_HOST} would be seen as literal text in the regex.)
You can, however, use %{HTTP_HOST} in the TestString (first argument) and modify the regex accordingly using an internal backreference to achieve the same goal.
For example:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([\w.-]+)@https://\1/format/showfancy/
:

The @ is just an arbitrary character that is not expected to be a part of the captured hostname.
The \1 in the CondPattern (2nd argument) is an internal backreference to the value captured by the first capturing group in the regex, ie. the value of the HTTP_HOST server variable present in the TestString.
Note that unless you are canonicalising the requested hostname prior to this rule then the use of HTTP_HOST here potentially allows the resource to be accessed via a non-canonical hostname.
Prevent the resource being cached
And, as mentioned in comments, if you don't want the client to be able to access this resource again later without going from the desired Referer (after having already accessed the resource via that Referer) then you need to disable client-side caching for this resource to ensure that all requests for this resource (URL) are sent to the server and not handled locally.
This is regardless of whatever form of client-side "authorisation" you are using.
For example, using mod_headers (which will override mod_expires - if you are using that already) you could add something like the following to your .htaccess file:
# Prevent client-side caching of this resource
<Files "fancy.pdf">
    Header always set Cache-Control "no-store"
    Header always set Expires "0"
</Files>

Naturally, you will need to make sure your browser cache is already cleared before testing this.

Thank you so much for all of that information! I've noted them in my documentation. I have applied your suggestions. I realised (and tested) that you can add the backslash in front of all of the dots in both RewriteCond and RewriteRule; presumably it would be more efficient. I notice that I cannot use %{HTTP_HOST} instead of hard-coding the domain name in RewriteCond.

Unfortunately, it's unreliable: On starting the browser, or after accessing the showfancy page, I can access the PDF using a direct link! Refresh the page or revisit it, and only then it gives 403, reliably. But, close and reopen the browser, or revisit showfancy, and the direct link again available! Hmm, I'll have to figure out an alternative method. Thank you again for your help — I've learned a lot.

@PaddyLandau Yes, the literal dots in the regex (RewriteRule pattern and RewriteCond CondPattern) should be backslash-escaped in order to match a literal dot and not any character. (This isn't for "efficiency", but because it would otherwise potentially match too much. Although it's unlikely to make any real world difference. I had accidentally omitted the backslash in the domain name of the CondPattern - now fixed.) You can't use %{HTTP_HOST} directly because that argument is a standard regex (PCRE) which does not support variable parsing.

@PaddyLandau However, you can still make use of %{HTTP_HOST} here - I'll update my answer with an example. (However, by using the HTTP_HOST variable and not hardcoding the domain (arguably a more reliable solution) you will potentially allow the resource to be accessed by a non-canonical hostname, eg. www.example.com, unless you have implemented a canonical redirect earlier in your code.)

@PaddyLandau "Unfortunately, it's unreliable:" - Well, if you have previously accessed this resource (PDF file) via the correct Referer then the browser has likely cached it locally, so further requests for the same URL are simply pulled from local cache (no request is sent to your server). If that is not desirable then you need to disable local caching of this resource on the server (by sending back the appropriate HTTP response headers at the time the resource is requested) - so any request for this URL is always sent to the server. This applies to any form of authentication.

@PaddyLandau Although relying on the Referer has its problems, as mentioned in the last couple of points in my answer.

@PaddyLandau I've updated my answer addressing the above points in detail.

Thank you, again! Unfortunately, even using the cache control as you suggested didn't solve the problem. My guess is that the browser doesn't properly obey the directive. I've solved the problem by using a PHP file that returns the PDF if the referrer is correct, otherwise it returns forbidden. I appreciate the time and effort that you've put into answering my question, and I've learned a lot.

I should add to my previous comment that the PDF file is now stored outside the website root, so it cannot be accessed directly ever. And, I had ensured that all caches were cleared, including the CDN.
